# View that joins 2 tables of similar structure will not Update (because it contains a derived or constant field)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm getting an error:

```
Msg 4406, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Update or insert of view or function 'dbo.vwEmployeeAll' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.
```

Yet, I have no derived or constant in my view.
The columns in my view all exist.  It's fairly straightforward in the example below.

```
-- START TSQL

SET NOCOUNT ON


IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'vwEmployeeAll' and TABLE_TYPE = N'VIEW' ) 
    BEGIN 
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[vwEmployeeAll] 
    END 
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'Employee' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
    BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] 
    END 
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'Employee' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
    BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employee] 
    END 
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'Department' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
    BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
    END 
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
    [DepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )


ALTER TABLE dbo.[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Department PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([DepartmentUUID]) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DepartmentName_Unique UNIQUE ([DepartmentName]) 
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ( 

    /* [EmployeeUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, */
    [EmployeeSurrogateKey] int not null IDENTITY(1,2), 
    [ParentDepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SSN] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EmployeeSurrogateKey) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Employee_SSN_Unique UNIQUE (SSN) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeToDepartment FOREIGN KEY (ParentDepartmentUUID) REFERENCES dbo.Department (DepartmentUUID) 
GO

/*
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Employee_PK_IsOdd] CHECK ( ( [EmployeeSurrogateKey] % 2 ) != 0)
GO
*/


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] ( 

    /*[EmployeeDeprecatedUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,*/
    [EmployeeDeprecatedSurrogateKey] int not null IDENTITY(2,2), 
    [ParentDepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SSN] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.[EmployeeDeprecated] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EmployeeDeprecated PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EmployeeDeprecatedSurrogateKey) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_EmployeeDeprecated_SSN_Unique UNIQUE (SSN) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeDeprecatedToDepartment FOREIGN KEY (ParentDepartmentUUID) REFERENCES dbo.Department (DepartmentUUID) 
GO

/*
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated]
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_EmployeeDeprecated_PK_IsEven] CHECK ( ( [EmployeeDeprecatedSurrogateKey] % 2 ) = 0)
GO
*/



CREATE VIEW dbo.vwEmployeeAll AS

Select 
    EmployeeSurrogateKey,ParentDepartmentUUID,TheVersionProperty,SSN,LastName,FirstName,CreateDate,UpdateDate,HireDate 
from dbo.Employee
UNION --ALL
Select 
/* EmployeeSurrogateKey =  */
EmployeeDeprecatedSurrogateKey ,ParentDepartmentUUID,TheVersionProperty,SSN,LastName,FirstName,CreateDate,UpdateDate,HireDate
from dbo.EmployeeDeprecated

GO


declare @DepartmentUUID001 uniqueidentifier
select @DepartmentUUID001 = 'DDDDDDDD-0000-0000-0000-000000000101'

declare @DepartmentUUID002 uniqueidentifier
select @DepartmentUUID002 = 'DDDDDDDD-0000-0000-0000-000000000102'

INSERT INTO dbo.Department (DepartmentUUID , DepartmentName , CreateDate )
Select @DepartmentUUID001 , 'Department One' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION 
Select @DepartmentUUID002 , 'Department Two' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP


/*
declare @EmployeeUUID001  uniqueidentifier
select @EmployeeUUID001 = 'EEEEEEEE-0000-0000-0000-000000001001'
declare @EmployeeUUID00A  uniqueidentifier
select @EmployeeUUID00A = 'EEEEEEEE-0000-0000-AAAA-000000009001'
*/


INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (/*EmployeeUUID,*/ParentDepartmentUUID,SSN,LastName,FirstName,CreateDate,UpdateDate,HireDate)
Select /*@EmployeeUUID001 ,*/ @DepartmentUUID001 , '111-11-1111' , 'Smith', 'John' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  , '01/01/2001'


INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeDeprecated(/*EmployeeDeprecatedUUID,*/ParentDepartmentUUID,SSN,LastName,FirstName,CreateDate,UpdateDate,HireDate)
Select /*@EmployeeUUID00A ,*/ @DepartmentUUID002 , '888-88-8888' , 'Jones', 'Mary' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  , '02/02/2002'


GO

Select * from dbo.vwEmployeeAll


Update dbo.vwEmployeeAll Set UpdateDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

EDIT:

Timestamp throws it for a loop.

Partitioned view 'ViewUpdateableDB.dbo.vwEmployeeAll' is not updatable because table '[ViewUpdateableDB].[dbo].[Employee]' has a timestamp column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update data in a view that uses a UNION when your primary keys are Identity. You must have a Partitioning Column. Otherwise, how would it know which table to update?

IE, you are using 2 tables that have a primary key on an identity field. They could have a {PK} = 1 in both tables. How would SQL Server know which table to update.

Comment: You can update a view that uses a UNION provided the primary keys have  constraints on them that keep them distinct. That's how partitioned tables work.

Comment: Ok..with that hint, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216586/t-sql-union-all-view-not-updatable-because-a-partitioning-column-was-not-found

Comment: Great.  Partitioned view 'ViewUpdateableDB.dbo.vwEmployeeAll' is not updatable because table '[ViewUpdateableDB].[dbo].[Employee]' has a timestamp column.

Comment: Using DavidG's hint and the URL, I revamped the question.

Comment: You have basically changed the entire question based on the fact that you got a new error. You should have created a new question.

Comment: I reverted the question back to the original.

Comment: A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using the set operators UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a computation and are also not updatable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Comment: Please "edit" your answer (slightly) so I can upvote it.  I now understand the disconnect I originally had.  So there is a way to do a Update-View with the addition of a "Partitioning Column".  So the msdn link I just posted above isn't exactly correct.  You can do a "UNION ALL" with a partitioning column....even in Sql Express version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example...with "UNION ALL" and a Partitioning Column.

I am posting this, because there is a specific way to get it to work....despite the msdn documentation.

> A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that
>   uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using the set operators
>   UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a
>   computation and are also not updatable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

So Steve's answer is correct based on the documentation and under most scenarios, but by using a partitioning-column there is a way to make it work.

The script/example below worked with Developer Edition (which is Enterprise Version without the licensing) and I tested it against SqlExpress ( Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
 )

```
Select @@VERSION

-- START TSQL

SET NOCOUNT ON


IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'vwEmployeeAll' and TABLE_TYPE = N'VIEW' ) 
    BEGIN 
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[vwEmployeeAll] 
    END 
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'Employee' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
    BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] 
    END 
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'Employee' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
    BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employee] 
    END 
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'Department' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
    BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
    END 
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
    [DepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )


ALTER TABLE dbo.[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Department PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([DepartmentUUID]) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DepartmentName_Unique UNIQUE ([DepartmentName]) 
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ( 

    /* [EmployeeUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, */
    [EmployeeSurrogateKey] int not null IDENTITY(101,2), 
    [EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal] int not null, 
    [ParentDepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    /*[TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,*/
    [SSN] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EmployeeSurrogateKey,EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Employee_SSN_Unique UNIQUE (SSN) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeToDepartment FOREIGN KEY (ParentDepartmentUUID) REFERENCES dbo.Department (DepartmentUUID) 
GO

/*
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Employee_PK_IsOdd] CHECK ( ( [EmployeeSurrogateKey] % 2 ) != 0)
GO
*/

/*
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Employee_PK_IsOdd] 
CHECK ( ( [EmployeeSurrogateKey] % 2 ) != 0)
GO
*/

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal_Is_One] 
CHECK ( [EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal] = 1 )
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] ( 

    /*[EmployeeDeprecatedUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,*/
    [EmployeeDeprecatedSurrogateKey] int not null IDENTITY(102,2), 
    [EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal] int not null, 
    [ParentDepartmentUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    /*[TheVersionProperty] [timestamp] NOT NULL,*/ /* Partitioned view 'ViewUpdateableDB.dbo.vwEmployeeAll' is not updatable because table '[ViewUpdateableDB].[dbo].[Employee]' has a timestamp column. */
    [SSN] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.[EmployeeDeprecated] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EmployeeDeprecated PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EmployeeDeprecatedSurrogateKey,EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_EmployeeDeprecated_SSN_Unique UNIQUE (SSN) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeDeprecatedToDepartment FOREIGN KEY (ParentDepartmentUUID) REFERENCES dbo.Department (DepartmentUUID) 
GO

/*
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated]
ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_EmployeeDeprecated_PK_IsEven] CHECK ( ( [EmployeeDeprecatedSurrogateKey] % 2 ) = 0)
GO
*/
/*
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_EmployeeDeprecated_PK_IsEven] 
CHECK  ( ( [EmployeeDeprecatedSurrogateKey] % 2 ) = 0)
GO
*/

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDeprecated] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal_Is_Two] 
CHECK ( [EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal] = 2 )
GO


CREATE VIEW dbo.vwEmployeeAll AS

Select 
    EmployeeSurrogateKey,EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal,ParentDepartmentUUID,SSN,LastName,FirstName,CreateDate,UpdateDate,HireDate 
from dbo.Employee
UNION ALL
Select 
EmployeeSurrogateKey =
EmployeeDeprecatedSurrogateKey,EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal,ParentDepartmentUUID,SSN,LastName,FirstName,CreateDate,UpdateDate,HireDate
from dbo.EmployeeDeprecated

GO


declare @DepartmentUUID001 uniqueidentifier
select @DepartmentUUID001 = 'DDDDDDDD-0000-0000-0000-000000000101'

declare @DepartmentUUID002 uniqueidentifier
select @DepartmentUUID002 = 'DDDDDDDD-0000-0000-0000-000000000102'

INSERT INTO dbo.Department (DepartmentUUID , DepartmentName , CreateDate )
Select @DepartmentUUID001 , 'Department One' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION 
Select @DepartmentUUID002 , 'Department Two' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP


/*
declare @EmployeeUUID001  uniqueidentifier
select @EmployeeUUID001 = 'EEEEEEEE-0000-0000-0000-000000001001'
declare @EmployeeUUID00A  uniqueidentifier
select @EmployeeUUID00A = 'EEEEEEEE-0000-0000-AAAA-000000009001'
*/


INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (/*EmployeeUUID,*/ParentDepartmentUUID,SSN,LastName,FirstName,CreateDate,UpdateDate,HireDate,EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal)
Select /*@EmployeeUUID001 ,*/ @DepartmentUUID001 , '111-11-1111' , 'Smith', 'John' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  , '01/01/2001' , 1


INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeDeprecated(/*EmployeeDeprecatedUUID,*/ParentDepartmentUUID,SSN,LastName,FirstName,CreateDate,UpdateDate,HireDate,EmployeeTablePartitionOrdinal)
Select /*@EmployeeUUID00A ,*/ @DepartmentUUID002 , '888-88-8888' , 'Jones', 'Mary' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  , '02/02/2002' , 2


GO

Select * from dbo.vwEmployeeAll


Update dbo.vwEmployeeAll Set UpdateDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP


Update dbo.vwEmployeeAll Set LastName = 'Henderson' where EmployeeSurrogateKey = 1

Update dbo.vwEmployeeAll Set UpdateDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where EmployeeSurrogateKey = 2
```

Comment: This question also talks about partitioning column.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216586/t-sql-union-all-view-not-updatable-because-a-partitioning-column-was-not-found