# Create indeterminant CHECK CONSTRAINT that works in SQL Server Partitioned View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-view

### Context

A SQL partitioned view reads tables like any other view. However, what makes them special is that they allow me to write to the underlying tables through when a portioning key column is indicated by using a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on the underlying tables.

- Read more in the [Online Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#partitioned-views).

### An Example

For example, here a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` validates the [Year] column value is always `2022`. The value of `2022` in the `CHECK` is a hard coded (deterministic) value. During a `SELECT` operation, the view ignores the `CHECK` but during an `INSERT` operation, the `CHECK` instructs the view to which table it should insert the record(s).

```
CREATE TABLE Part2022 
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE CLUSTERED
  , Year INT CONSTRAINT req2022 CHECK (Year = 2022) 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id, Year)
);
```

Using this approach, a partitioning view would look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW Parts AS
            SELECT * FROM Part2022
  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Part2021
  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Part2020
```

This works just fine.

### The question

I understand the issue, but I wonder if some clever data engineer out there has figured a workaround that would enable a different approach - something similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE PartCurrent
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE CLUSTERED
  , Year INT CONSTRAINT reqCurrent CHECK (Year = YEAR(GETUTCDATE())) 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id, Year)
);
```

Of course, this does not work. Though the `CHECK CONSTRAINT` can be applied to the table without issue, including this table in a partitioned view now results in:

> Msg 4436, Level 16, State 12, Line 53 view is not updatable because a partitioning column was not found.

**Q: Is there a way to use an indeterminate `CHECK CONSTRAINT` with a partitioned view?**

PS: I know what partitioned tables are and when to use them in a model. In this case, though, they do not meet the requirements. As a result, I am asking about partitioned views.  Thx.

Comment: It's not quite a four letter word, but "triggers" feel like a good fit here. Specifically, keep the `(Year = 2022)` style constraints on the tables that constitute the view but put an insert trigger on the view that checks if any of the data attempting to be inserted through it violates your business rule that only data in the current year be inserted. I will also point out what I see as a potential way for this to blow up in that data for December 31 is going to be tricky to load. My guess is that what you've laid out is merely an example, but still...

Comment: Is this similar question helped you? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216586/t-sql-union-all-view-not-updatable-because-a-partitioning-column-was-not-found)

Comment: Wow @PratikLad you have amazing search skills. That is amazingly similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** Though a check constraint condition can be dynamic in a table, if that table is in a partition view, checks on partition key columns must be hardcoded. This is by design.

- Read the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

That is to say, you must do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Part2022 
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE CLUSTERED
  , Year INT CONSTRAINT req2022 CHECK (Year = 2022) 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id, Year)
);
```

You cannot do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Part2022 
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE CLUSTERED
  , Year INT CONSTRAINT req2022 CHECK (Year = YEAR(GETUTCDATE())) 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id, Year)
);
```